# Eclipse C++: No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.cdt.ui.editor.CEditor

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to run a project but for some unknown reason every time I pull up Eclipse, I get this error message: `No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.cdt.ui.editor.CEditor`. This has never happened before and I'm on a deadline. I have the stack-trace, but it is very long so if you need to see it please let me know.

Comment: That sound like your Eclipse installation is broken. Make sure you have [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers **2020-09**](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-09/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers) and do not waste time with outdated software.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but haven't found the solution to it yet.

The issue appears to be that the latest versions of CDT require JDK11 or later to work. With my Eclipse 2020-06 install, if I use JDK11 or later CDT works, if I switch back to JDK8 (a.k.a. JDK1.8) then it gives the error you reported.

Unfortunately, the plugin I use for one of my ARM debugger/programmers still requires something from JDK8 and won't start the debugging process under JDK11.

At the moment it is looking like the solution is going to be re-install 2020-06 and stop it getting any of the later updates.

-Andy.